# add similar header files in goldfish kernel

Tags: android, c, kernel-module

I wrote loadable kernel module and test it on phone, but now i want to test it on emulator.
I use `msm kernel` to build that module,and use some headers in `msm kernel` like

> msm_smd.h

but emulator use goldfish kernel and doesn't contain that header .
is there any way to use msm kernel and boot it on emulator (i ask bcz i build it but msm kernel dont boot on emulator)?
or how can i find similar header for goldfish kernel?
really need help

Comment: Good question but hard to answer, I did your tasks a couple of months ago,, I will explain them to you in a separate answer below

Answer (score 0):

Porting an msm kernel to goldfish board (i.e. google virtual board that Android emulator is based on) is a tedious approach and needs an expert. So, I advise you to find the exact source code of your pre-built goldfish kernel, integrate your module inside it, re-compile and test it.
However, I still can provide you with all the steps needed to port the msm kernel -or any other kernel- to goldfish board, **if this is really needed**.

If you are using goldfish kernel 3.4 -which is the kernel version on default SDK emulator- then here is the source on AOSP:
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/+/android-goldfish-3.4

Kernel version can be dumped to screen using adb utility:

> adb shell cat /proc/version

To compile goldfish kernel, you need first to install arm eabi cross compilation toolchain:

> *git clone* https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8
>
> Add **bin** directory to your PATH variable, since it contains the required compiler and linker
>
> *export ARCH=arm*
>
> *export SUBARCH=arm*
>
> *export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-*
>
> *make goldfish_armv7_defconfig*
>
> *make -j4*

After a successful compilation, the kernel image can be found under:
$KERNEL_SRC/arch/arm/boot/**zImage**

Now, Backup your default SDK goldfish kernel (i.e. named as kernel-qemu), then  use the newly built **zImage** instead of it

Hope this helps